# Function to submit form by id

Tags: javascript, forms

How can I submit form using form id as function param? Would it be something like that:

**HTML:**

```
<a href="#" onclick="confirmSubmit(form1)">Delete file</a>
```

**Javascript:**

```
function confirmSubmit(id) {
    var agree=confirm("Are you sure you wish to delete this file?");
    if (agree)
        document.getElementById('form' + id).submit();
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: _Would it be something like that_ So you haven't tried it yet?

Comment: @Andreas, yes I have but 1) it doesn't work 2) i was wondering if there is some easier way

Comment: 1) That should be part of the question, including the error message(s)  2) Is the second step after 1) has been resolved because your code should work if you enclose the parameter in the `onclick` attribute with quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass form id as string parameter(means with in single quotes) to the onClick function.

see below

```
<a href="#" onclick="confirmSubmit('form1')">Delete file</a>
function confirmSubmit(id) {
    var agree=confirm("Are you sure you wish to delete this file?");
    if (agree)
      document.getElementById(id).submit();
    else
     return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Define an id to form (if you want to refer by ID)

```
<form id="form">

</form>

<a href="#" onclick="confirmSubmit('form')">Delete file</a>

function confirmSubmit(id) {
    var agree=confirm("Are you sure you wish to delete this file?");
    if (agree)
        document.getElementById(id).submit();
    else
        return false;
}
```